# Javascript function to change the value of an ASP Textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This is a little strange.  I've got this segmenty of ASP in my code:

```
<td style="line-height: 230%;">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtePro" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Font-Size="Small"
    Height="18px" Width="100px" Visible="False" Wrap="False" 
    OnTextChanged="txtEPro_OnLeave" OnFocus="txtEPro_OnFocus()" 
    AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MeeePro" runat="server" Mask="9999999" MaskType="None"
    TargetControlID="txtePro" PromptCharacter="_" />
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MeePRD" runat="server" Mask="999999" MaskType="None"
    TargetControlID="txtePro" PromptCharacter="_" />
```

I also have the following function in the same ASP file:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function txtEPro_OnFocus() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('txtePro');
        elem.value = "";

        alert("Hello there");
    }

</script>
```

If I comment out the first 2 lines of the Javascript function, I get prompted with a box that says, "Hello there".  So, I know the function is firing in the OnFocus event.  However, when I put those first 2 lines back into the function, it says it can't find "txtePro".  It errors on the

```
elem.value = "";
```

line and says,

> Unhandled exception at line 176, column 13 in Default.aspx
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of
>   the property 'value': object is null or undefined

If I hover my mouse over "elem", it shows the value as "NULL".

Any ideas?

Comment: Remember, ASP.NET mangles the IDs by default - the client-side ID of the element is almost certainly *not* `txtePro`, but rather `someContainerID_someParentID_txtePro`, which is why JavaScript can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of the textbox is changed by ASP.NET, so it won't be 'txtePro' after it's rendered on the server.  Instead of referencing that in your JS function, try using inline C# to get the proper ID.

```
function txtEPro_OnFocus() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('<%= txtePro.ClientID %>');
    elem.value = "";

    alert("Hello there");
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ.  Thanks!